# How to handle 2 different versions(free, pro) database requirement

Tags: vb.net

I am planning to write an application which will be available in 2 versions. one free and the other one paid.

The only difference is that in free versions only a maximum of 2 DB entries are allowed. but its unlimited in paid version.

DB does not have more than 1 table with 5/6 fields.

I am planning to use xml for free version and SQLite for paid version. Is this ok? are there any other options?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use SQLite for both versions?  It seems lot a lot of unnecessary work to support both data stores.

Comment: OK thanks!! What do you think is the best method to restrict the entries for the free version?

Comment: There are lots of ways to do it, but just add a check that there aren't more than 2 records before inserting new ones, or if you want to allow replacement just put a TOP 2/LIMIT 2 in the query text.